# Dynamic search form given number of input values with the collection

Tags: java

My form contains 6 fields: fName, lName, mName, age, sex, sal

We can't expect that the user will complete all the inputs. Sometimes he completes only 3 inputs and sometimes 4, sometimes only 1 and sometimes all, we can't predict it.

I have an employee bean that has all 6 properties with values.

I want to search this employee bean with all the given inputs from the user. That means I need to dynamically identify which getter to use for the comparison. If the user has given only 3 inputs, then I need to use respective getters only for the comparison.

Comment: So what is your question? [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: And what is your question? What you wrote sounds like an assignmentdescription. Do you want us to give you an Answer or to do your job? Ask a question. Show us what you tried and what didn't work.

Comment: What have you already done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection. For example if your user privided age and sex you should invoke `getAge()` and `getSex()` and compare them with given values. To compose the getter name use code like the following:

`String getterName = "get" + fieldName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + fieldName.substring(1);`

Now you can invoke it:

`String value = String.valueOf(Person.getCalss().getMethod(getterName).invoke(person));`

Now just compare it with given value.

You can also use libraries that simplify bean access for you. For example [BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/) from jakarta project.

Comment: thank you sir, you helped me alot.I'm a fresher I dont know about this approach. Now I got it.once again thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like Hamcrest Matchers.  For example:

```
String MATCH_ANY = "matchany83102176193580";

...

if (mName.equals(search.mName) || mName.equals(MATCH_ANY))
```